# Recovering a web part back to it's component .ascx files in a Visual Studio Project?

Tags: 2013, web-part, decompile

So in a freak accident I deleted my documents  directory on my development machine, whoops :-)

In doing so I lost some changes before I had a chance to check them into version control.  Quite a few of them and fairly significant.

However I did make a deployment of my web part to test servers, and pulled back the .wsp files for inspection.  When I decompiled the resulting assemblies in DotPeek I see plenty of code that inlines my .ascx files into the code.  Albeit pretty badly formed.  Basically something like this:

__ctrl.AddParsedSubObject((object) new LiteralControl("\r\n\r\n

Has anyone else had to do the same thing I've done.  Any gadgets that can help?  Thanks!

Comment: if you have a wsp, you should be able to make a new project out of it by importing it into VS, last I knew.

Comment: Not really, doesn't import the .ascx files into seperate files from the .dll, it just builds a .wsp file that deploys the entire .dll with assemblies and all other extracted features.  Though I had to try it to verify though.

Comment: well I did manage to resolve the urgency by scraping out code from other sources,, but I'm leaving the question open to see if anyone has dealt with this before.